# UID value arduino uno

Tags: programming

How to read UID value in arduino uno to PHP language? 
before, thanks for a lot

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this library: https://github.com/rubberneck/php-serial

On GNU/Linux, you may need to be a member of the ‘dialout’ group. Ubuntu solves this problem by making its users members of every group, so you may not need to edit `/etc/group`

Once you have connected via a USB or USB-TTL cable (the latter will not force a reset upon connect), use a buffer to store all the reads, then parse them.

Comment: I using OS Windows sir, How?

Comment: @AsepERoni Nevermind, try that library. It will work on Linux, OSX, Windows.

Comment: wheter have his way? step by step, because I fairly new for this is..

Comment: @AsepERoni Connect to COM1 (or whatever port is used), read data into a buffer, parse it, use it.

Comment: @AsepERoni Is the question answered? If yes, please mark it as such.

Comment: i having trouble, at the time of convert Heksadecimal to normal number? how?

Comment: @AsepERoni It’s internally just in binary. Define a format with e.g. sprintf( bar, “%i”, foo ), or if using serial, Serial.print( foo, DEC ). Split the UID into a 7-byte array with strtok(). There’s no reason to use decimal for the UID...

Comment: do you have example?

Comment: @AsepERoni `for ( int i=0; i<7; i++) Serial.println( uid[i] )` ... it will be null-terminated so try `while ( uid[i++] != ‘\0’ ) Serial.println( uid[i] )` as well. I don’t remember the type used in the PN532 example, IIRC char array. It doesn’t matter... format the output to be adequate for your PHP script, and if you need it to be non-blocking, look in the PN532.cpp file. Change the timeout.

Comment: why 7 in looping for?

Comment: @AsepERoni use the variable `uidLength` instead of 7. The variable `uid` is a char array IIRC, so will have no problem with it. PHP is like Perl, so just use join() and split() equivalents.